# Ignoring minwidth in css

Tags: html, css

i just found out that Chrome is ignoring CSS `min-width: ...;` . I can't find solution to fix it, can you please give me some ideas? Checked on mozzila firefox and IE 9, on them it works just great! All answers will be appreciated!
Thanks ;)!
EDIT: fixe d;)

Comment: Chrome is not ignoring `min-width`, show us the code that gives you problems. Unless you are actually writing `min:width` and it's not an error in your question, then it would make perfect sense.

Comment: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/), please.

Comment: In jsFiddle everything is okay, dunno why... Deleted 2nd question, sorry.

Comment: If there's no way to reproduce this, how do you expect to get a solution? CSS alone is not enough, need to see the HTML as well. As little code as possible to reproduce the problem. `min-width` does in fact work in Chrome, but you may have another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you said:

> In jsFiddle everything is okay, dunno why...

If this is true, then the problem is probably a non-visible character in your css file (eg. a control character, or other unicode character).  Get a text editor (like [Textwrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)) that can show un-printables and/or purge them for you.

Alternately, you might consider copying the code back out of jsFiddle, and pasting it into a clean text file.

Comment: i got windows :(, so i can't install .dmg files

Comment: How does this explain why it would work in one browser but not another?

Comment: there are plenty of windows text editors that will show you stray non-printables. (I just can't recommend any, because I don't use windows).

Comment: @WesleyMurch - different browsers handle charset-related issues (including stray non-printables) differently.  This is especially true in css and javascript files (as opposed to HTML source).  I'm not saying that this *is definitely* the problem, but the OP's assertion regarding jsFiddle leads me to suggest this as a strong possibility.

Comment: Lol! Fixed it by removing spaces after a link in div tag :).
WOOHOO :D thanks!